# regular expression for find [# # 1] , [# # 2] ,[# # 125] .. in php

Tags: php, regex

regular expression for find [# # 1] , [# # 2] ,[# # 125] .. in php

i have string

```
"php, regu[]lar expre[# # 1]ssio [# # 2]nssadas das dasd as das dasdssd [# # 301]dfs dfsdf sd fsdfds"
```

want to replace all these with `{number}`

Comment: I see you have an empty "[]", what would you like to do with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you do it like this

```
$string=preg_replace('/\[#\s#\s([0-9]+)\]/', '$1', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
theString.preg_replace( '/\([#\s#\s[0-9]+\])/', '$1' );
```

Edit: ok, some miner mistakes here but u get the idea :p.

Comment: you're escaping the ( instead of the [